# Is it possible to set up Travis for a project for which you are a collaborator?

Tags: travis-ci

So, I'm set up on GitHub as a collaborator for a project owned by another user
(I have full push rights, etc).  Is it possible for me to set up Travis for
this project?  I could not find the repository on the "Repositories" list in
Travis.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Only a repository administrator can enable the hook, so you need one of the repository administrators to log onto Travis CI to enable the repository. Everything else can be done by a collaborator.

Comment: @henrikhonde: Then can i maintain that travis setup using my travis account (as a collaborator). Will it automatically come under my tab?